# Citizen Erased: My Mac deleted my user account! Please help

Tags: macos, user-account, leopard

The last time I used my user account I was browsing the net and sending an email with the built in Mail app. But I accidentally unplugged the Mac and when it came back, my user account wasn't on the Login screen anymore. 
I tried using this guide:
http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-rebuild-a-user-account-in-os-x/

And after trying to recreate the account, nothing happens. So I turn to the Console log to see what's going on, and I get this:
[image: console log]

It's like OS X blacklisted my username or something like that. Also, I noticed was that my user account folder no longer has a pretty house on it and instead has that ugly default folder icon.

[image: /users/ folder]

Anyway, even though this is an old PowerBook G4 with OS X 10.5 on it I hope you'll be able to help me out claim my account back.

Comment: Only the currently signed in user folder has a home icon, so that’s not an issue

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution on https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2760585:

1. boot up using your SL disk.
2. select 'change password'
3. reset the root password
4. restart the mac from the system drive
5. log in as root
6. open system preferences
7. create an account with the SAME FULL NAME and ACCOUNT NAME as your 'lost' account
8. you will be prompted that "a folder with said name already exists - would you like to use the existing folder?" - SELECT OK
9. log out of root
10. log into your account